# Is IE11 webdriver support in linux for selenium testing?

Tags: linux, selenium, internet-explorer-11, ubuntu-16.04

I for now do need to run IE 11 in Ubuntu 16.04 for selenium test cases.

Using Wine and PlayOnLinux can be helpful but there is no IE 11 as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer is a product of Microsoft and It can only work properly with Windows OS.

There is no any official way suggested by the Microsoft to install the Internet Explorer on Ubuntu OS.

There are some tricks or hacks available with the help of that somehow you can manage to install the older version of IE on your Ubuntu OS but it's performance will be very low. It can get hang or crashed frequently. Also Ubuntu does not has the appropriate directory structure, environment and other settings which are necessary to run IE properly.

The best work around for using IE on Ubuntu OS is to install any Windows OS using virtual machine. Than you can try to access that Windows OS from your Ubuntu OS and try to run your tests with IE browser.

**There is also no selenium Web driver support for IE on Linux OS.**